# Congruence and division

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove using congruence that $111^{333}+333^{111}$ is divisible by 7?

I tried use each factor separately but I didn't really get anywhere.
Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$111 \equiv -1 \pmod{7} \implies 111^{333} \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$$
$$333 \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \implies 333^{3} \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies 333^{111} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$
Hence, you get $$111^{333} + 333^{111} \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Comment: how did you get in the second line from 4 mod 7 to 1 mod 7? This is where I was stuck when trying to solve..

Comment: @Nusha Marvis used $4^3=64=63+1$

Answer (score 4):

$$111\equiv -1\pmod 7\implies 111^{333}\equiv (-1)^{333}=-1$$

$$333\equiv 4\pmod 7=2^2$$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{7-1}\equiv 1\pmod 7$

$$333^{111}\equiv (2^2)^{111}\pmod 7\equiv (2^6)^{37}\equiv 1\pmod 7$$

---

Alternatively, $333^3\equiv 2^6\equiv1$ and $111^9\equiv-1\pmod 7$

So, $7\mid(333^3+111^9)$

But $(333^3+111^9)\mid \{(333^3)^{37}+(111^9)^{37}\}$